# Counting sequences with exactly d distinct elements

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of sequences $(x_1,...,x_q) \in \mathcal{X}^q$ with exactly $d$ distinct elements, for some $1 \leq d \leq q$?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what $X$ is, but if it has $x$ elements, then the answer is
$\binom{x}d$ times the solution when $X=\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$. In that case, the solution is the number of surjections from $\{1,2,\ldots,q\}$
to $\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ which is $d!S(q,d)$ with $S(q,d)$ a Stirling number of
the second kind.